# What is the difference between test and testl and testb

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have the 3 following assembly lines and in a function and I don't why test/testl/testb is being used. I tried googling but couldn't find any answers:

```
   testl  $0x1000000,(%rax)
   test   %rdx,%rdx
   testb  $0x4,0x830(%rdx)
```

I know test performs the AND, and from my code testl is doing the same since the line is `x & 0x1000000`. So what do these different test instructions do?

Comment: Operand size. `l` is long, 4 bytes. `b` is byte. Suffix can be omitted if it can be deduced from the operand, as in the second case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the suffixes specifying the size of the operands. See: [GAS_Syntax - Operation_Suffixes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes):

> GAS assembly instructions are generally suffixed with the letters "b", "s", "w", "l", "q" or "t" to determine what size operand is being manipulated.
>
> - `b` = byte (8 bit).
> - `s` = single (32-bit floating point).
> - `w` = word (16 bit).
> - `l` = long (32 bit integer or 64-bit floating point).
> - `q` = quad (64 bit).
> - `t` = ten bytes (80-bit floating point).
>
> If the suffix is not specified, and there are no memory operands for the instruction, GAS infers the operand size from the size of the destination register operand (the final operand).

Comment: That final paragraph from wikibooks is way too restrictive.  GAS can infer the operand size for `test %eax, (%rdx)` just fine, even though it does have a memory operand, and the final operand is memory.  Since almost all instructions (e.g. not `movzbl` / `movsbl`) require every operand to be the same size, *any* register operand is sufficient.  The only ambiguous case is `op $imm, mem`, or one-operand instructions like `op mem`.  That's only wikibooks, but actual GAS documentation (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html) doesn't spell things out as nicely.

Answer (score 1):

When you test with registers, the size of the operands are known and so you only need to use `test`. When you test using memory and an immediate, you need to specify the size of the operands. So `testb` tells the assembler to test a byte (8 bits) and `testl` is to test 32 bits.